# An etale cover of a semiperfect ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, etale-cohomology

Assume that $R$ is a semiperfect ring in characteristic $p$,i.e the frobenius is surjective on $R$. I think one can prove that an etale cover of $R$ should again be semiperfect by considering the basic etale maps simmilar to the fact that an algebraic extension of a perfect field is again perfect. Is this true and has anyone a better proof or a reference for this fact?

Answer (score 0):

This is true. A non-ideal reference is in the proof of Lemma 1.5 of my [joint paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2310.08472.pdf), but the proof is simple enough that one should just write the proof themselves if they need it.

> **Proposition:** Let $R$ be a semi-perfect $\mathbb{F}_p$-algebra, and $R\to S$ and etale map. Then, $S$ is semi-perfect.

*Proof:* By definition $\mathrm{Frob}_R\colon R\to R$ is surjective, and thus the same holds true for $S\to S\otimes_{R,\mathrm{Frob}_R}R$. But, as $R\to S$ is etale, this map may be identified with $\mathrm{Frob}_S$ (e.g., see [Tag 0EBS](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0EBS)). $\blacksquare$